# One input field value should not be greater than other field value of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am asking this question again because i  have a new issue in it.
I have two input fields one for advance payment and other for full payment, which are fetched from the database in array.

If `onchange` or `keyup` the advance payment is greater than full payment, Then the advance payment should not be entered or should be equal to full payment.

i have got the following answer previously which worked for me, But now i have a new issue in it. it works with existing data which are fetched from the database in array form. But when i increase a new row with JavaScript it is not working in it.

I am trying with this code

```js
$('.advance').on('change keyup blur', function(e) {
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");
    var fullPay = $('#fullPayment_' + id[1]).val();
    var advancePay = $('#advancePayment_' + id[1]).val();
    if ($(this).val() > parseInt(fullPay)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(fullPay);
    }
});


var i = $('table tr').length;

$("#newRow").on('click', function() {
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" value="15" id="fullPayment_' + i + '"></td>';

    html += '<td><input type="number" id="advancePayment_' + i + '" class="advance"></td>';

    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" value="12" id="fullPayment_1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="advancePayment_1" class="advance">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" value="19" id="fullPayment_2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="advancePayment_2" class="advance">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="newRow"> + Add </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the event handler to this format:

```
$(document).on('change keyup blur','.advance', function(e){... });
```

More about event delegation here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/3643/

```js
$(document).on('change keyup blur', '.advance', function(e) {
  id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
  id = id_arr.split("_");
  var fullPay = $('#fullPayment_' + id[1]).val();
  var advancePay = $('#advancePayment_' + id[1]).val();
  if ($(this).val() > parseInt(fullPay)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(fullPay);
  }
});


var i = $('table tr').length;
$("#newRow").on('click', function() {
  html = '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" value="15" id="fullPayment_' + i + '"></td>';

  html += '<td><input type="number" id="advancePayment_' + i + '" class="advance"></td>';

  html += '</tr>';
  $('table').append(html);
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="12" id="fullPayment_1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="advancePayment_1" class="advance"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="19" id="fullPayment_2"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="advancePayment_2" class="advance"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="newRow"> + Add </button>
```

Comment: why the 1st increasing row value is 19 instead of 15.

Comment: @geeshak That you would have to figure out maybe. I showed you the actual cause why your code did not worked

Comment: sorry! for the late response, Thank you for your solution. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be a lot more dynamic and automated.

Perhaps something like this;

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="12" id="fullPayment_1" class="fullPayment"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0" id="advancePayment_1" class="advance"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="19" id="fullPayment_2" class="fullPayment"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0" id="advancePayment_2" class="advance"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


$(function() {

//Put it on the parent element so new inputs have the binding too
  $('table').on('keyup', '.advance', function() {
  //Get the together belonging advance and fullpayment rows
    var $advance = $(this);
    var $fullPayment = $(this).parents('tr').find('.fullPayment');
    //Pars the values to numerics for a good comparison
    var advanceValue = parseFloat($advance.val());
    var fullValue = parseFloat($fullPayment.val());
    console.log(advanceValue, fullValue)
    if (advanceValue > fullValue) {
      $advance.val(fullValue);
    }

  });

});
```

See this working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0czh087/1/)

Comment: thanks for you answer, But it's not working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0czh087/2/) .

Comment: what's not working exactly? It's working for me 100% fine, unless I understood what you wanted wrong